# How to overcome the limitation of `PERCENTILE_CONT` that the argument should be constant?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find `POINTCOUNT` values that cut the input set `ADS.PREDICTOR` into equally large groups. The parameter `POINTCOUNT` can have different value for different predictors, so I don't want to hard-code it in the code.

Unfortunately the code below fails with `ORA-30496: Argument should be a constant`... How can I overcome this (except for 300 lines of code with hard-coded threshold quantiles, of course)?

```
define POINTCOUNT=300;
select
    *
from (
select
    percentile_disc(MYQUNTILE)
        within group (
            order by PREDICTOR ) as THRESHOLD
from ADS
inner join (
    select (LEVEL - 1)/(&POINTCOUNT-1) as MYQUANTILE
    from dual
    connect by LEVEL <= &POINTCOUNT
    )
on 1=1
)
group by THRESHOLD
```

I want to draw a ROC curve. The curve will be plotted in Excel as a linear interpolation between pairs of points (X, Y) calculated in Oracle.

Each point (X, Y) is calculated using a threshold value.

I will get the best approximation of the ROC curve for a give number of the pairs of points if the distance between each adjacent pair of (X, Y) is uniform.

if I cut the domain of the predicted values into N values that separate 1/Nth quantiles, I should get a fairly good set of the threshold values.

Comment: This is doable with some plsql and dynamic ddl, but I don't have time at hand to write it. Just shoot the select with percentile_disc with an execute_immediate and catch the results in collections or in a table.

Answer (score 1):

`PERCENTILE_CONT()` only requires that the percentile value be constant *within* each group.  You do not have a `group by` in your subquery, so I think this might fix your problem:

```
select MYQUANTILE,
       percentile_disc(MYQUANTILE) within group (order by PREDICTOR
                                                ) as THRESHOLD
from ADS cross join
     (select (LEVEL - 1)/(&POINTCOUNT-1) as MYQUANTILE
      from dual
      connect by LEVEL <= &POINTCOUNT
     )
GROUP BY MYQUANTILE;
```

Also, note that `CROSS JOIN` is the same as `INNER JOIN . . . ON 1=1`.